# What value we have to give for match in template tag?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

> Source xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Inbound Message -->
<Sales xmlns="abc:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4/xcbl4.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
</Sales>
```

> Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Sales">
    </xsl:template>
```

> Query: In the source xml, Sales root node tag contains the below
>   values.  xmlns="abc:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4/xcbl4.xsd"
>   xmlns:SOAPENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding
>
> How to start the template?

```
<xsl:template match="/Sales'> 
<xsl:template match="/'>
```

> Above code is not working. Please help me to resolve this issue

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare namespace in XSLT, then use qualified name, e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns="abc:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4/xcbl4.xsd">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ns:Sales">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Kirill, Could you please tell me why do we need to use ns:. Do I need to add the same for child nodes as well. How to retrive the child nodes?

Comment: @Sara, That is because elements in your XML are located in namespace. To retrieve child elements you can use fully qualified name (with prefix) or for example `<xsl:template match="/ns:Sales">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>`. This will apply templates to all child elements.